# How to click an element in javascript using click() and then execute another function?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am trying to create an extension where I open a chrome tab and then click a button in that DOM and then close that tab.

So below is JS file in which the function gets executed once the window gets loaded. But I don't know a way to add a callback to click function

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementsByClassName(<className>).click()
   window.close()
}
```

Comment: you don;t need a callback. clicks happen synchronously, so just add the code you want to execute on click after you programmatically click the button..

Comment: Hey, you can go though the [onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) event handler for more information on executing function after .click()

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Okay the problem is when I click the button I am closing the window without waiting for the result of the click. How to resolve this issue? How to wait for sometime till click button action has happened?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. So I added a delay of 3seconds to window.close() function and it's working fine but the thing is if someone has slow internet then it many take more than 3seconds for the click to happen. so anyway to resolve that

Comment: what you want to to have a callback for the click button's other handler, not for the click itself. without seeing *that* code no one can tell you how to hook into it, if that's even possible.

Comment: The code I posted is a script which gets executed when my chrome extension  is used. The button is add to cart button. So I want to click add to cart button and wait for the item to get added to the cart and then close the window. But now what is happening is the button is getting clicked and immediately window is getting closed without waiting for the item to actually get added

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment "I want to click add to cart button and wait for the item to get added to the cart and then close the window" I think you are looking at this wrong.

Your onload function should perform the click.

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementsByClassName(<className>).click()
}
```

Then some other function should close the window after detecting the item was added to the cart

```
[some other event] = function() {
   window.close()
}
```

The some other event could be detecting onchange of some other element that shows the item in the cart. It's hard to know without seeing the page.

If it needs to be independent of the design of the website, I don't have a good suggestion. Even with a "callback to click function", every website might handle the click differently. Some may have a submit button that does a HTTP POST. Others might be an Ajax call that is either synchronous or asynchronous. Others might use javascript to update some other elements of the DOM, which themselves trigger an event that triggers a click. These are just examples and there are likely other cases. Detecting the "click" won't detect the item in the cart.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I want to make it general not just specific for some website. That's the reason item being added to cart in one website might need a different way to detect from other websites